# Insert a new table in Excel when a new column is added to existing table

Tags: excel, insert, vba

I have a spreadsheet with one BIG table in the top half, and corresponding "mini tables" in the bottom half.  Each time I add a new column to the BIG table, I need a new "mini table" to be automatically added below.  Can anyone help me with a VBA code that will do this?  In my sample, let's say that column F was the last column in the BIG table.  When I add column G, I need the "mini table" that begins in cell A 29 to be automatically created.  Is this even possible?

[image: Sample]

Comment: How would Excel know which columns you need in the "mini table"? How do you determine the number of rows you need in the "mini table"? And, of course, post your code so far and explain where you are stuck. If you don't want to or can't write the code, please hire a developer.

Comment: You actually insert a column by "Insert column" action or just by Enter a new value/label to row 3? Beside, this post show no effort of you to make it.